# Accuracy and output from project tango

Tags: 3d, google-project-tango, revit

Can we import the output from Project tango to rivet software to analyse the existing building details. And also how accurate will be the output?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question will depend on the implementation, and this is probably not the best forum to answer it.

Accuracy: the project Tango tablet can be used to measure dimensions in 3-D space and has roughly a 1% accuracy for distance measurements. Thus, nearby objects will have greater measurement accuracy than distant ones.